# How to make Windows Input Simulator accept variables?

Tags: c#, windows, input, simulator

I'm working on a personal project that uses Windows Input Simulator. 
(https://inputsimulator.codeplex.com/)

I'm trying to make it accept a variable but am have no luck whatsoever.
When `Case: "WIN"` happens it runs the following code.

`InputSimulator.SimulateModifiedKeyStroke(VirtualKeyCode.LWIN, VirtualKeyCode.VK_R);`

Which works great but I'm wondering if I could have the `VirtualKeyCode.VK_R` part be dynamic. For example if `Keys = "F"` then run 
`InputSimulator.SimulateModifiedKeyStroke(VirtualKeyCode.LWIN, VirtualKeyCode.VK_F);`

Basically I want to have `VK_(variable)` but I'm not sure how to implement this.
I thought an array of values that hold its vk value, for example `F = VK_F` etc. But I have no idea how to put that variable in the function.

Any help would be very appreciated. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want the `VirtualKeyCode` `enum` value from the string letter? In that case construct the `enum`:

```
    string your_letter = "F";
    VirtualKeyCode code;
    if (Enum.TryParse<VirtualKeyCode>("VK_" + your_letter, out code))
    {
         InputSimulator.SimulateModifiedKeyStroke(VirtualKeyCode.LWIN, code);
    }
```